# How do I stop a two dimensional int array from outputting its values once an int <= 0 is entered?

Tags: java, arrays

the method with an array:

```
void outputBock(int [][] block)
```

The first Dimension saves blocks, the second Dimension numbers that are in the blocks.

(Numbers in the block are saved by the input in the console) (function for that already there.)

When the user types in a value <= 0; the Array has to stop printing the number from within the block after that specific number.

The two-dimensional Array:

```
 {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
 {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
 {18, 15, 17, 19, 14},
 {26, 47, 58, 59, 60}}
```

is being printed like this:

```
  block 1: 1 2 3 4 5
  block 2: 6 7 8 9 10
  block 3: 18 15 17 19 14
  block 4: 26 47 58 59 60
```

The two dimensional Array:

```
  {{3, 2, 1, 0, -1},
  {9, 7,11 12, 13, 14},
  {15, 16, 17, 108, 19},
  {20, 21, 22, 23, 24}}
```

is being printed like this:

```
  block 1: 3 2 1
  block 2: 9 7 11 12 13 14
  block 3: 15 16 17 18 19
  block 4: 20 21 22 23 24
```

Any idea how I can stop the array from printing out numbers within a block once something <= is typed in?

Comment: Could you post the part of code / logic that is reponsible for doing the actual print statements? I think we wanna see the guts of `void outputBock(int [][] block)`

Comment: Try using ```break``` statements in your loop whenever you encounter a negative number break from the inner loop to the next iteration.

Comment: @SomilGarg thank you I will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `break` statements in your code.

> When the break statement is encountered inside a loop, the loop is immediately terminated and the program control resumes at the next statement following the loop.

```java
void print(){

       int[][] array = {
                         {3, 2, 1, 0, -1},
                         {9, 7,11 ,12, 13, 14},
                         {15, 16, 17, 18, 19},
                         {20, 21, 22, 23, 24}
                       } ;
       for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
           System.out.print("block "+ (i+1)+" ");//Prints the block number
           for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++) {
               if(array[i][j] <= 0) {
                   break; 
                   //Goes to the next iteration of outer for loop.
               }
               else {
                   System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");
               }
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this later and tell you if it worked. Thy!

Comment: with an array like this: public static int selectBox(int player, int[][] playerBox) {
  } How do I check if the second Dimension (sec. Brackets) are empty?

Comment: @asdfafa You can use playerBox[i].length == 0 for that . The above code will work for that condition aswell . When any index is {} the second loop will not run.